# Super resolution implementation with RS-ESRGAN

Tags: sentinel-2, satellite, google-colab

I am trying to implement super resolution to my satellite images using RS-ESRGAN (please see https://github.com/luissalgueiro/rs-esrgan/tree/master).
There are three things to adjust before running `python /rs-esrgan/train_esrgan_WV.py -opt /rs-esrgan/options/train/train_ESRGAN_WV_5x_ALL.json` command and start the training, such as:

1. Use JSON files to configure options.
2. Convert the JSON file to Python dict.
3. Support // comments and use null for None.

I have configured a .json file named "train_ESRGAN_WV_5x_ALL.json" in train folder. Then, converted it to Python dict with the code blocks below:

```py
import json

with open('/content/rs-esrgan/options/train/train_ESRGAN_WV_5x_ALL.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)

details = {'use_tb_logger': True, 'model': 'srragan', 'scale': 5, 'gpu_ids': [0], 'datasets': {'train': {'name': 'GDAL', 'mode': 'NoUpsamplingGDAL_PretrainRGB_ALL', 'data_IDs': '/content/datasets/bandas_all.csv', 'dataroot_HR': '/content/datasets/train/', 'dataroot_LR': '/content/datasets/train_LR/', 'subset_file': None, 'use_shuffle': True, 'n_workers': 1, 'batch_size': 2, 'HR_size': 140, 'use_flip': True, 'use_rot': True, 'stand': True, 'LR_down': True, 'PreUP': True, 'norm': False, 'up_lr': False, 'HF': False, 'scale': 5}, 'val': {'name': 'val_GDAL', 'mode': 'NoUpsamplingGDAL_PretrainRGB_ALL', 'data_IDs': '/content/datasets/valid.csv', 'dataroot_HR': '/content/datasets/val/', 'dataroot_LR': '/content/datasets/val_LR/', 'HR_size': 140, 'stand': True, 'norm': False, 'LR_down': True, 'PreUP': True, 'up_lr': False, 'HF': False, 'scale': 5}}, 'path': {'root': '/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR', 'work_root': '/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR_2020/', 'resume_state': '/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR_2020/experiments/P41_ESRGAN_ALL_L1_x5_PREUP_FT_StanData/training_state/80000.tf'}, 'network_G': {'which_model_G': 'RRDB_net', 'norm_type': None, 'mode': 'CNA', 'nf': 64, 'nb': 23, 'in_nc': 4, 'out_nc': 4}, 'network_D': {'which_model_D': 'discriminator_vgg_128', 'norm_type': None, 'act_type': 'leakyrelu', 'mode': 'CNA', 'nf': 64, 'in_nc': 3}, 'train': {'lr_G': 0.0001, 'weight_decay_G': 0, 'beta1_G': 0.9, 'lr_D': 0.0001, 'weight_decay_D': 0, 'beta1_D': 0.9, 'lr_scheme': 'MultiStepLR', 'lr_steps': [20000, 40000, 60000, 80000], 'lr_gamma': 0.5, 'pixel_criterion': 'l1', 'pixel_weight': 0.01, 'feature_criterion': 'l1', 'feature_weight': 1, 'gan_type': 'vanilla', 'gan_weight': 0.005, 'manual_seed': 100, 'niter': 101000, 'val_freq': 10000}, 'logger': {'print_freq': 100, 'save_checkpoint_freq': 10000}}
  
with open("myfile.json", 'w') as f: 
    for key, value in details.items(): 
        f.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))
```

Even though I configured, converted the JSON file to Python dict, and wrote my file with `json.dumps()`, when training the command, it gave me an error like this:

```
DATASET items <built-in method items of NoneDict object at 0x7f997ae8c0f8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/rs-esrgan/train_esrgan_WV.py", line 299, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/rs-esrgan/train_esrgan_WV.py", line 52, in main
    resume_state = torch.load(opt['path']['resume_state'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 608, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 777, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Where do you think I am going wrong?

Comment: You didn't include the resulting contents of `myfile.json`, but it's not in JSON format (no leading/trailing curly braces, and JSON requires quotes around strings). You should write the file with `json.dumps()` (with an `indent` parameter to make it human-readable at first)

Comment: Thanks, I will try json.dumps().

Comment: I wrote the file with json.dumps() and name it sample.json. After that, training command gave me an error like this:
EOFError: Ran out of input. What does it mean?